# Detect caret movement in Text control

Tags: java, swt, listener, caret

I feel really stupid, but I can't seem to get a listener be notified when the user changes the caret in a `Text` or `StyledText` input field. I've tried `SelectionListener` as well as `CaretListener` (StyledText only), but none gets reliable called when I'm moving the caret inside a multi-line input field using the arrow-keys. The `CaretListener` sometimes gets invoked, but, for example, not after having selected all text and hit `Del`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listening to `SWT.MouseUp` and `SWT.KeyUp` seems to be the way to go in your case:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    Listener listener = new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            System.out.println("Event");
        }
    };

    text.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, listener);
    text.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, listener);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose(); 
}
```

You could keep track of the old caret position with a `static` variable and compare it to the current position in the `Listener`.

---

Another very handy event is `SWT.Verify` which is called whenever a change occurred to the contained text. Note that this would not take care of position changes with the mouse.